# Cannot add backdrop attribute on jQuery opened Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable, modal-dialog

Good day everyone.

Im having trouble on setting a backdrop attribute on a jQuery opened modal. 
Im using a dataTable plugin for my table design any i created a group of DataTable buttons that each will display modal. And by the way Im using ASP.net MVC 4. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code for my DataTable table:

```
<table id="exampledatatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" >
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Customer Code</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Customer Type</th>
        <th>Industry Type</th>
        <th>Website</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Off Day 1</th>
        <th>Off Day 2</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Tiger</td>
        <td>Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
        <td>5421</td>
        <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my code for my DataTable buttons

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#exampledatatable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Create New Record',
                action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
                    $('#generalCusModal12').show();
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Edit Existing Record'
            },
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Delete Existing Record'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Restore Deleted Record'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Refresh Records'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Print Records'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Close'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

And here is my Modal pop up

```
<div id="generalCusModal12" class="modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header modal-header-employee">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title"><img class="crud" src="~/Images/profile.png" />Customer Records Management</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 class="lbl_custinfo">General</h4>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Code</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="<Auto>" disabled>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Company Type</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1" disabled>
                            <option value="">CUSTOMER</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Customer Type</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="" selected></option>
                            <option>WALK-IN</option>
                            <option>RESIDENTIAL</option>
                            <option>COMPANY</option>
                            <option>SCHOOL</option>
                            <option>BANK</option>
                            <option>CLINIC</option>
                            <option>RESTAURANT</option>
                            <option>HOSPITAL</option>
                            <option>HOTEL</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Industry Type</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <option>ADVERTISING AGENCIES</option>
                            <option>BUSINESS PROCESS OUTSOURCING</option>
                            <option>ENTERTAINMENT COMPANY</option>
                            <option>FOOD COMPANY</option>
                            <option>TECHNOLOGY</option>
                            <option>TELECOMMUNICATION</option>
                            <option>PHARMACEUTICAL</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Day Off 1</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <option>MONDAY</option>
                            <option>TUESDAY</option>
                            <option>WEDNESDAY</option>
                            <option>THURSDAY</option>
                            <option>FRIDAY</option>
                            <option>SATURDAY</option>
                            <option>SUNDAY</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Day Off 2</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
                            <option value="" selected disabled></option>
                            <option>MONDAY</option>
                            <option>TUESDAY</option>
                            <option>WEDNESDAY</option>
                            <option>THURSDAY</option>
                            <option>FRIDAY</option>
                            <option>SATURDAY</option>
                            <option>SUNDAY</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label">Website</label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label class="col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-4 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-6">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" style="min-width: 100%"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div><!--MODAL BODY-->

            <div class="modal-footer">

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#custLocationModal" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Next</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call modal like this

```
$('#generalCusModal').modal('show');
```

Instead of

```
$('body').addClass('modal-open');
$('#generalCusModal12').show();
```

see [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-options)

**Note:**  you are also giving wrong ID in Javascript `generalCusModal12` where your ID is `generalCusModal`

Comment: Sorry. I've copy a different modal. but with regard to your suggestion, I already Tried your code in the past. but It doesn't seems to work, it cannot even open the modal and i dont no why.

Comment: Have you use bootstrap modal ? Or any error on console

Comment: yes. im using a bootstrap modal. And i dont have any errors on console

Comment: This is impossible then that bootstrap builtin modal function is not work check spelling of Id may be you have something different error

Comment: As i see you are calling generalCusModal12 where your modal ID is generalCusModal as i mentioned in the ans